# Weak Toilet Flush after not being used for Two months

Tags: plumbing, toilet

After not being used for two months, one of the toilets in my home does not flush properly.

The water level in the toilet bowl is very low, just barely up to the opening. However, in the tank, the water is an inch below the fill line, where it should be. Upon flushing, the bowl fills up nearly to the top and then quickly drains to almost no water in a few seconds.

I have tried pouring a few gallons of water down the bowl and flushing and the same issue occurs. I've also tried plunging the toilet with a toilet plunger after I fill up the bowl and that doesn't fill up the bowl either.

It might be worth mentioning that I live in a new house (about one and a half years old) and probably have one of those water saving toilets. The brand of the toilet is "Contrac".

Is there anything else I can do sort of calling a professional?

Comment: It sounds like there's a problem with the drain or drain vent downstream of the toilet. I doubt the period of disuse is related.

Comment: It does sound like blockage in the pipe, the symptoms sound like a loaded drain line.   How non-use can be a factor is if waste was sitting in the pipe and dried out and solidified blocking part of the line.  You don’t say where this is located, and in North America it hasn’t recently been tree root growing season, but another non-use factor is tree roots have time to overtake an old tile sewer in that period of time— if that’s the problem they would have anyway but your introduction to the problem would have been slower over time.

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you mean by "an inch below the fill line"?